# Unable to import apps from settings.py's INSTALLED_APPS list

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm hitting an error when running `makemigrations`, and it seems to be related to my `INSTALLED_APPS` list.

Here is a screenshot of my project:
[image: project overview]

and here is the error:
[image: error]

I've also attempted to use the following strings in the `INSTALLED_APPS` list, but I got the same error:

```
    '.api.apps.ApiConfig',
    '.pizzas.apps.PizzasConfig',
```

The classes `ApiConfig` and `PizzaConfig` both follow this structure in their respective `apps.py` files:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class PizzasConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'pizzas'
```

Does anyone have any ideas as to what I could be missing here?

Comment: Rin: `python manage.py dbshell`.   Then `import api`.   Whats the output?

Comment: Still getting the same error when I try to run `python manage.py dbshell`

Answer (score 1):

In some cases when you make a circular import between two or more apps (could be on models, views, any place) the django can't import propely when startup and shows this error.

Try comment all the code from the views.py in api and restart the project to see if works.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when I had created an application with name `t`. However, it resolved when I used configs for registering it inside installed apps.

I believe you have a typo in the config names. An extra dot `.` at the beginning.

Try this one.

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'api.apps.ApiConfig',
    'pizzas.apps.PizzasConfig',
]
```

Comment: Same result :-(